# Ubuntu 14.04 Share files with Samsung Tablet

Tags: 14.04, usb, samsung, tablet, transfer

How can I use my USB to transfer files to/from my 14.04 to/from Samsung Tablet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would you be OK doing this another way ? I installed airdroid on all my android devices, its a free app. Simply run airdroid and connect to your android device via the wifi. File transfer both ways, as well as control of your contacts, sms etc. I have never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable your tablet as a Multimedia Transfer Protocol device (you should be able to change this setting in USB settings. Also, disable USB debugging in developer options)
On your Ubuntu machine you should install MTP tools and MTPFS.

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools
```

To be able to mount it as a filesystem, install mtpfs

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mtp-tools

http://www.adebenham.com/mtpfs/